# How do affixes affect Elite's names?

Tags: diablo-iii

I noticed sometimes when I meet an elite (yellow name) in Diablo 3 their name reflects their affixes. I had found something on a wiki but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Can someone explain it to me please?

Edit: Here [it is](http://www.diablowiki.com/Rare_Monsters), I found the page I was talking about.

Comment: I don't think there is any connection between Elite's name and his affixes. Would you mind providing a bit more info? Something like names and affixes of the Elites

Comment: They don't.  Names are random for elites and champions.  The only ones with set names are uniques.

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think its totally random, such as the rare weapon names aren't totally random as some of it is based on the affix on the weapon.  I.e. gluttonous for anything with life on hit

Comment: maybe its pure coincidence but I ran into 2 monsters with the 'hoard' affix called Alot <something or the other> last night.

Comment: @yx There's a finite amount of prefixes and suffixes available, for both elites, or rare items.  Rare item names ARE completely random; just check the AH for Life on Hit items; there won't be any rhyme or reason to them.  Elites might slightly different, but the amount of names available is smaller than it is for items; I'd suspect it's coincidence.

Comment: @fbueckert the name is simply based off of one possible affix.  For example, just because it has loh on it doesn't mean it'll always be called gluttonous.  What will or won't prove this though will be whether or not the 'gluttonous' name appears on a weapon without the loh affix.  Again, I'm just using the word gluttonous as an example as I'm on in game right now so I don't know if that's really even a possible name.  What I do know though is that I've only seen names such as 'backhand i.e. monstrous backhand' and 'slap i.e. fiery slap' etc on monk fists and no other weapon types.

Comment: Hmm.  Based on that logic, certain affixes may *allow* more name choices, opening the pool to slightly more variety.  Perhaps this question isn't as meaningless as I originally thought.

Comment: I think what yx meant to say was that Elite names (by elites I mean monsters with yellow names) are based on affixes like Magic items. Rare items are completely random, but Magic affixes are not. I guess more testing is required to see if it effects Yellow elies in the same way.

Comment: @thegatekeeper rare items are not completely random though, find me a rare weapon that's not a monk fist with the word 'backhand' as the suffix.

Comment: No idea about rare weapons, but it could be the case.

Comment: I just found a rare with the affix "Reflector" and it had a reflect damage affix. I think you may be right.

Answer (score 1):

The [gamepedia page](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Rare_Monsters) says that there are eight prefixes and eight suffixes that indicate particular affixes (Fast and Frozen).

```
+-------------+-----------------------+
|            Fast                     |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| Prefix      | Suffix                |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| Valafar     | Swiftspite            |
| Breakneck   | the Quickened         |
| Kazfiel     | , Dispatcher of Faith |
| Hastus      | Siezefrenzy           |
+-------------+-----------------------+

+-------------+-----------------------+
|           Frozen                    |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| Prefix      | Suffix                |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| Deumos      | the Embalmed          |
| Marax       | the Ice Lord          |
| Chulock     | Winterfang            |
| Shiverstark | Soulfreeze            |
+-------------+-----------------------+
```

So if you see a rare named Alot Swiftspite, then you know that it has the Fast affix.  Similarly Chulock, Crippler of Princes would have the Frozen affix.  I suppose that Kazfiel the Ice Lord would be both Fast and Frozen.  Not sure if that ever happens.

That page also has a long list of prefixes and suffixes that it says are randomly assigned and mean nothing.